# How to collect the intersection and both complements of two arrays within one task?

Tags: javascript, arrays, intersection, array-difference, complement

Arrays -

```
const source = [1, 1, 1, 3, 4];
const target = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6];
```

Empty arrays -

```
const matches1 = [];
const matches2 = [];
const unmatches1 = [];
```

Loop -

```
for (const line of source) {
  const line2Match = target.find((line2) => {
    const isMatch = line === line2;
    return isMatch;
  });

  if (line2Match) {
    matches1.push(
      line
    );
    matches2.push(line2Match);
  } else {
    unmatches1.push(line);
  }
}
```

This is the output right now -

`[ 1, 1, 1, 4 ]` ​​​​​at ​​​​​​​​matches1​​​

`[ 3 ]` ​​​​​at ​​​​​​​​unmatches1​​​

`[ 1, 1, 1, 4 ]` ​​​​​at ​​​​​​​​matches2​​​

The desired output -

`[ 1, 4 ]` ​​​​​at ​​​​​​​​matches1​​​

`[ 1, 1, 3 ]` ​​​​​at ​​​​​​​​unmatches1​​​

`[ 1, 4 ]` ​​​​​at ​​​​​​​​matches2​​​

What I would like to add is when `source` has a match with `target`, the value will be deleted from the `target` array, how can I achive that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the difference between two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: once again. what is the difference between `matches1` and `matches2`?

Comment: @pilchard ty, but no.
I don't need to get the difference, I need to remove a value from target array if he found a match

Comment: @NinaScholz
On the real arrays they will have different values.
Is my question clear?

Comment: no. please use an example which makes the difference clear.

Comment: This is an XY Question. The linked duplicate offers solutions for intersection, difference and symetric difference, which covers your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Just for matches1:
(similar for matches2)

```
const source = [1, 1, 1, 3, 4];
const target = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6];

let matches1 = source.reduce((res, curr)  => {
    if (target.includes(curr) && !res.includes(curr)) {
        res.push(curr);
    }
    return res;
}, []
);

console.log(matches1)
//[1,4]
```

For unmatches1:

```
let unmatches1 = source.reduce((res, curr)  => {
    if ((target.includes(curr) && res[0].includes(curr)) || !target.includes(curr)) {    
        res[1].push(curr);
    }
    if (target.includes(curr)) {
        res[0].push(curr)
    }
    return res;
}, [[],[]]
)[1]

console.log(unmatches1)
//[1,1,3]
```

To achieve the unmatches2 result [2,5,6] - just replace source and target at the input, or at the code, or extend the code tho have both outputs. It's simple.

Comment: The OP actually wants to know how, in addition to what the OP already has accomplished, an `unmatches2` like calculation of e.g. `[2, 5, 6]` can be achieved.

Comment: I didn't really understand the comment. Please be more clear. My solution provides an expected output on provided input, that was not achieved by the code provided in the question. It was a matter of the question.
Aha, specifically, to get [2,5,6] just replace source and target - or as input, or in the code. It's simple.

Comment: BTW the additional requirement of doing this by one task was added much later. It's the wrong way to add such significant editing a few hours after opening the question.

Comment: The OP was very specific about what the OP wants to achieve with the provided source code ... _""What I would **like to add** is when **source has a match with target**, the **value will be deleted from the target array**, how can I achive that?""_  ... which of cause can be translated to ... _How to collect the intersection and both complements of two arrays within one task?_

Comment: Well, there are actually 2 not-related questions: 
The first one said "This is the output right now - <...>The desired output -<...>", probably meaning that the algorithm in the question doesn't work as desired.
As soon as desired output didn't match the actual - I provided a solution that works as "desired".  
The second question mentioned by you could be easily solved based on the solution I provided to the first one.  Need to work a little bit :)
Well, the arguing becomes boring. Good luck :)

Answer (score -1):

The OP ...

> *"What I would like to add is when source has a match with target, the value will be deleted from the target array, how can I achive that?"*

One had to actively mutate the `target` array by slicing the common item from it which in the very end makes `target` become the relative complement
of `source` in `target` ... commonly/vulgo ... the ***target difference***.

One of cause could apply a shallow copy of `target` as part of the [*initial value*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#how_reduce_works_with_an_initial_value) of a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) task in order to not mutate the original `target` reference itself ...

```js
function collectIntersectionAndComplements(collector, sourceItem) {
  const { targetDiff } = collector;

  const targetIndex = targetDiff
    .findIndex(targetItem => targetItem === sourceItem);

  if (targetIndex === -1) {

    // collect the relative complement of target
    // in source ... vulgo ... the source difference.
    (collector.sourceDiff ??= [])
      .push(sourceItem)
  } else {

    // collect the intersection of both source and target ...
    (collector.intersection ??= [])
      .push(
        // ... by rejecting the common item from the original
        // target, thus actively mutating the latter, which leads
        // to ending up additionally with the relative complement
        // of source in target ... vulgo ... the target difference.
        targetDiff.splice(targetIndex, 1)[0]
      );
  }
  return collector;
}

const source = [1, 1, 1, 3, 4];
const target = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6];
const {

  intersection,
  sourceDiff,
  targetDiff,

} = source.reduce(collectIntersectionAndComplements, { targetDiff: [...target] });

console.log({ source, target, intersection, sourceDiff, targetDiff });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

*@heyheyhey2* ... Btw, if one was talking about the [*Simple Theory of Sets*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Basic_operations) then duplicate (identical) values within each array/list/set were not allowed. Sets always have to feature just unique values.

Answer (score -2):

Note that for a single pass both arrays must have been sorted into ascending order.

```
function go(){
    const a = [0,1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 6,8,10];
    const b = [-3,-4,1, 2, 4, 5, 6,25,26];

    let nomatcha=[];
    let match=[];
    let nomatchb=[];
    let i=0,j=0;
    while(true){
        if(i>=a.length){
            for (;j<b.length;j++) nomatchb.push(b[j]);
            break;
        }
        else if (j>=b.length){
            for (;i<a.length;i++) nomatcha.push(a[j]);
            break;
        }
        else if(a[i]==b[j]){
            match.push(a[i++]);
            j++;
        }
        else if (a[i]<b[j]){
            let val=a[i++];
            if(nomatcha.length==0)nomatcha.push(val);
            else if(val != nomatcha[nomatcha.length-1])
                nomatcha.push(val);
        }
        else if (b[j]<a[i]){
            let val=b[j++];
            if(nomatchb.length==0)nomatchb.push(val);
            else if(val != nomatchb[nomatchb.length-1])
                nomatchb.push(val);
        }


    }

    console.log("match: "+match);
    console.log("nomatcha: "+nomatcha);
    console.log("nomatchb: "+nomatchb);

}
```

}

Output:

match: 1,4,6
nomatcha: 0,1,3,8,10
nomatchb: -3,-4,2,5,25,26

Comment: Following the OP's example code and explanation the above received `nomatcha` value of `[0, 1, 3, 8, 10]` should be `[0, 1, 1, 3, 8, 10]`

Comment: I assumed no repetitions and also matches1 must clearly = matches 2